# Create Multi-Select List In Excel

Tags: list, excel, excel-2013, multi-select, vba

In Excel 2013, I know natively there is no way to create a multi-select list.  What is the best option for creating a multi-select list in Excel?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps use the data validation function.

Comment: Any example of how to do such?

Comment: Or Combo Box on in the User form option in Developer

Comment: I was wanting a way to just place it on a cell itself.  Could I use a combo-box that way or would it have to be palced on a user form?

Comment: I put a pic in your post about Data Validation let me know if it is useful

Comment: see if this helps http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/drop-down-list.html

Comment: I have my current drop down set-up similarly, but I want to be able to select multiple items.

Comment: In the example I gave you you can see Pizza, Pancake and Chinese. So you have three options available in one cell with a drop down. So I am not really understanding your issue.

Comment: I want to be able to select both pizza and pancake or all 3 items.  Not just a single item from the list.  Does that help clarify?

Comment: hhm yep I think I do. Can you get a pic up of your sheet? Have you heard of a Combo Box and User form?

Comment: Yes, I know about a userform and a combo box.  Is it possible to create a combo box directly on the sheet itself w/o creating a user form?

Comment: I know how to add the combo-box directly to the sheet, how can I populate it and make it multi-select?

Comment: I found this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-list-box-or-combo-box-to-a-worksheet-555bee5f-96e6-4047-a469-78e4f1d988b3 I think you want the list box active control. I am trying out on my own sheet here at the moment

Comment: Sorry SmallFries I am all out of ideas at the moment. I am trying to get it going on my own sheet here. If I succeed I will let you know.

Comment: if you can get to youtube this is where I am https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ulIraDmhF0o